# PARI/GP --- Converting Calculated Output to Binary

Tags: math-software

I am new to using PARI/GP.

I would like to be able to make certain computations which PARI displays in decimal form (that is fine). But I want in the next step to convert the output to binary form with the same level of precision (I specify) that was used in the original computation.

PARI has a `binary' function but it displays the answer as a boxed sequence. I would like to display the output in ordinary form.

Can somebody advise me as to how this may be accomplished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code (binr() for reals, bin() for reals or integers):

```
binr(x)=my(v=apply(y->concat(apply(x->Str(x) ,y)), binary(x+0.))); concat([v[1],".", v[2]]);
bin(n)=if(type(n)=="t_INT",concat(apply(x->Str(x),binary(n))),binr(n));
```

may do what you want. So, for example after you enter the code for "binr(x)" and "bin(n)" then type

```
\p9
bin(543)
```

which produces

```
"1000011111"
```

and then try

```
 bin(1.375)
```

which produces

```
"1.0110000000000000000000000000000"
```

The real precision of 9 decimal digits is the minimum, but you can set it to higher precision.
Also, to get rid of the double quotes, just use "print()". For example,

```
print(bin(12345))
```

produces

```
11000000111001
```

There are probably other ways to do what you want depending on your exact situation. For example, if you just want to print the binary expansion of
a specific number, then you can use this code:

```
apply(x->print1(x),binary(12345));
```

which produces the same result using only built-in functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. The additional explanations are quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
? n=2^77+7
%3 = 151115727451828646838279
?
? b=binary(n)
%4 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
?
? for(i=1,#b,print1(b[i]))
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111
```

Comment: @Dimity Ezhov Thank you. The code you provided worked very nicely. I noticed that it is an expedient way of converting integers to binary. Do you know if there is a way to modify it so that it works for rationals too?

Comment: @mlchristians `f=12/9`, `n=binary(numerator(f))`, `d=binary(denominator(f))`, `for(i=1,#n,print1(n[i]));print1("/");for(i=1,#d,print1(d[i]))`.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is great, here is the GP-Pari script to convert from the binary string back into decimal.

```
{dec(S)=
local(L,pt,s,sz,i,p);
L=Vec(S);
pt=0;
p=1/2;
s=0;
sz=matsize(L)[2];
for(i=1,sz,
  if(pt==0,
    if(L[i]==".",pt=1;);
    if(L[i]=="1",s=2*s+1;);
    if(L[i]=="0",s=2*s;);
  ,
    if(L[i]=="1",s+=p;);
    p/=2;
  );
);
if(pt==1,s*=1.0);
return(s);
}
```